# Fixing wildcard expansion resulting in too many terms error (DRG-51030)

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, full-text-search

How can I resolve the `wildcard_maxterm` problem in Oracle 10g?

My index creation syntax is:

```
begin
    ctx_ddl.drop_preference('SUBSTRING_PREF');
end;
/

begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('SUBSTRING_PREF', 'BASIC_WORDLIST');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('SUBSTRING_PREF', 'SUBSTRING_INDEX','TRUE');
end;
/

begin
    ctx_ddl.drop_preference('bus_obj1_lexer');
end;
/

begin
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('bus_obj1_lexer','BASIC_LEXER');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('bus_obj1_lexer', 'base_letter', 'YES');
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('bus_obj1_lexer', 'mixed_case', 'YES' );
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('bus_obj1_lexer','printjoins', ';,@_');  
    ctx_ddl.set_attribute('bus_obj1_lexer','skipjoins', '-'); 
end;
/

create index BUS_OBJ_FTS_Name on BUSINESS_OBJECTS1(name)
  indextype is ctxsys.context 
  parameters ('wordlist SUBSTRING_PREF 
               MEMORY 128M 
               DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE
               SECTION GROUP CTXSYS.AUTO_SECTION_GROUP
               STOPLIST CTXSYS.EMPTY_STOPLIST                         
               LEXER bus_obj1_lexer                         
               SYNC (ON COMMIT)');
```

And my query is:

```
select * from BUSINESS_OBJECTS1 where contains(name,'%WIN%')>0 and rownum<=100;
```

There are 15 million rows in that table, and more than 50000 rows match that query. I have set `wildcard_maxterm=50000` and `default=20000` but I'm still getting this error:

> DRG-51030: wildcard query expansion resulted in too many terms.

Can anybody hep me how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The [wildcard_maxterm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm#i1008935) is set to the maximum. Actually, the maximum in 10g is 15,000. I think the best approach is to limit the search term. The [Oracle error action](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/drgus.htm#sthref17668) is to make the query narrower. Here is Oracle's [documentation on wildcards (%_)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm#CCREF0344). The % means zero or more characters. The _ means match in a single position. And 'WIN' is a broad term for a contains search.

I think you should try a very narrow query and then gradually broaden the query until you find right combinations. Can you remove the % before and after and try a % only at the end? Try to increase the characters before or after WIN. Try multiple queries for more specific terms. Try a fixed number of _ characters instead of a %?